# List outline of books related to another book by a node reference field

Tags: 7, views

I am using the book module with four content types: A, B,C and D.

A is the content type for child pages and the rest are allowed in book outlines.

I also have a node reference field in A that allows users to select nodes of type A related to the one they are creating.

I am trying to use views to display all the nodes that are related to a certain type A node and also display the outline of these related nodes.

E.g. viewing Book A.1 related topics and their outline:

- Book A.1

  - Book A.2

    - Page A.2.1
    - Page A.2.2
  - Book A.3

    - Page A.3.1
    - Page B.3.2
    - Page C.2.2

I have gotten as far as displaying all the related nodes to a certain node but I am not being able to display their outline.

Any help/critics appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried views to create the outline.

A simple custom module will also do the trick and then you can use the generated result to show in the block as outline. In my opinion this is the best and fastest possible way to do your job.

Comment: I am using views as I mentioned on the question, but once i get the nodes referenced I cant get their outline